# virtual socat serial port and c# on ubuntu linux

Tags: c#, serial-port, virtual-serial-port, socat

for testing purpose I'm trying to write a simple program that connect to a virtual serial port created with socat.

I create the serial port with this command:

```
socat -d -d PTY,b9600 PTY,link=ttyVS1,b9600
```

getting this output:

```
2011/11/08 18:26:31 socat[32708] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2011/11/08 18:26:31 socat[32708] N PTY is /dev/pts/2
2011/11/08 18:26:31 socat[32708] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [3,3] and [5,5]
```

When I try to connect in this way:

```
System.IO.Ports.SerialPort _port;
_port = new SerialPort("/dev/pts/1", 9600);
_port.Open();
```

I get a "filename unknown" `System.IO.IOException`.

Am I missing to set DataBits, StopBits or other parameters? How can I discover the properties sett by socat? Or what is wrong with this code?

Comment: Nothing related but just to mention ,at my Native Language Socat means "Retarded" =)

Answer (score 1):

What is wrong here is for sure the name of the device. Can you check at /dev that /dev/pts/1 exists? Maybe it has another name like /dev/pts1?

Comment: I will check and I'll post here... For now I can say that I've done another test with Windows using com0com (Virtual Serial Port software). I was able to run two instance of the same software (connecting without baudrate, just the port) and exchange data! I want to do the same with Ubuntu Linux (and aslo with Mac OS X)...

Comment: On linux the problemi is that, also if both /dev/pts/1 (and 2) exists, when I call Serial.GetPortNames() I can't see /dev/pts/* listed. Probably the Mono runtime acts like .NET runtime being not able to connect to port not named COM* (for linux could be /dev/tty*, I don't know!). Sounds correct? (Can I symlink resolve the problem?)

Comment: What do you have when calling GetPortNames()?

Comment: /dev/ttyS0
/dev/ttyS1
/dev/ttyS10
/dev/ttyS11
/dev/ttyS12
/dev/ttyS13
/dev/ttyS14
/dev/ttyS15
/dev/ttyS16
/dev/ttyS17
/dev/ttyS18
/dev/ttyS19
/dev/ttyS2
/dev/ttyS20
/dev/ttyS21
/dev/ttyS22
/dev/ttyS23
/dev/ttyS24
/dev/ttyS25
/dev/ttyS26
/dev/ttyS27
/dev/ttyS28
/dev/ttyS29
/dev/ttyS3
/dev/ttyS30
/dev/ttyS31
/dev/ttyS4
/dev/ttyS5
/dev/ttyS6
/dev/ttyS7
/dev/ttyS8
/dev/ttyS9

Comment: Ok, so we have 2 things to check. Or the Mono implementation of the serial port only support ports starting with /dev/ttySx or there is a bug at the method (mmm ... I don't know how the code would be able to know that /dev/pts/1 is a serial port anyway ...). Can you change the port that socat creates to a tty name? or link? or something like that? You get the idea ... I'm not a Linux expert ...

Comment: I've tried with a symbolink link (sudo ln -s /dev/pts/1 /dev/ttyS20 after renameing /dev/ttyS20.old) for both devices and I get the same exception. Any other idea? Thanks again.

Comment: Why not... I'll post here results! Thank you for your time.

Comment: Upvoted! I'm diving into mono/mcs/class/System/System.IO.Ports source directory. SerialPort.Open (on SerialPort.cs) consumes an internal class called SerialPortStream. This last type use an extern call defined as:[DllImport ("MonoPosixHelper", SetLastError = true)] static extern int open_serial (string portName);. Now we should go deep on this API!

Comment: Put your neoprene swimming suit ;) Good luck!

Comment: Finally surfaced! The code we care lives in this place of the source tree: **mono/support/serial.c**. The `open_serial(char*)` is defined here and performs a simple call to a system **open()**, like this: `open (devfile, O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NONBLOCK)`. open_serial() doesn't check the format of devfile parameter. Maybe that the **O_NOCTTY** flag enforce a device file and **/dev/pts/1** _created by socat_ is not recognized as device file. So the problem comes back to **socat**: how to run socat in a way that will allow the creation of valid device file?

Comment: I've started a small lib with inside some code for access serial data, [https://github.com/gsscoder/libfoundation](https://github.com/gsscoder/libfoundation). Serial mock  device included, for only for Windows (using **com0com**).

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this? I'm running into it as well.