# Issue passing valid command-line arguments for socat

Tags: socat, bash-on-windows

Whereas this works as expected:

```
root@LIM:~# socat -d -d pty pty
2017/10/15 01:01:49 socat[91] N PTY is /dev/pts/0
2017/10/15 01:01:49 socat[91] N PTY is /dev/pts/1
2017/10/15 01:01:49 socat[91] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [7,7]
```

Including any argument at all causes socat to fail:

```
root@LIM:~# socat -d -d pty,echo=0 pty
2017/10/15 01:04:56 socat[92] N PTY is /dev/pts/0
2017/10/15 01:04:56 socat[92] E tcsetattr(5, TCSADRAIN, 0x7fffdafe8be0): Invalid argument
2017/10/15 01:04:56 socat[92] N exit(1)
```

I'm following [this SO advice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8054652/virtual-socat-serial-port-and-c-sharp-on-ubuntu-linux), [this tutorial](http://carbidelabs.com/tutorials/serial-port-prototyping/), and [this blog](https://rabinnankhwa.wordpress.com/2013/12/25/creating-a-null-modem-virtual-serial-port-pair-connection-with-socat/) and ultimately want to run a command that may resemble `socat -d -d pty,link=/dev/ttyS0,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/dev/ttyS1,raw,echo=0` to establish a pair of virtual serial ports for COM1 and COM2.

I am using Bash on Ubuntu on Windows:

```
root@LIM:~# socat -V
socat by Gerhard Rieger - see www.dest-unreach.org
socat version 1.7.3.1 on Feb  2 2016 21:25:06
   running on Linux version #1-Microsoft Wed Dec 31 14:42:53 PST 2014, release 4.4.0-43-Microsoft, machine x86_64
features:
#not shown for brevity

root@LIM:~# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

C:\Users\Aaron Borns>ver
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.15063]
```

What is wrong with the command to cause the `Invalid argument` error? Thank you for your help!

Comment: The same socat command that fails above, is successful on an old Arch Linux box I have. I don't know why the command fails on BoUoW, any thoughts?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Comment: No, unfortunately. I changed my approach entirely to not use socat because of this.

Answer (score 0):

Upgrade to socat 1.7.4.4 at least. Under the *Corrections* heading of its `CHANGES` files you'll find:

> The rawer option failed because it tried to clear CREAD.

This helped me with a similar problem, hopefully it'll help you as well.